# php curl empity content

Tags: php, curl, download

using cURL I'm trying to transfer to my server a zip file from another server.
after authentication this second server gives me a url that contains even parameters as credentials:

```
http://content.website.com/file_to_download.zip?nvb=20160622094506&nva=20160622095506&hash=089366e5fe3da46f9caf2
```

if I surf this url to another web browser or on a private session I can download the content without problems (doesn't ask for login), but if I send the url to my function I get an empity file.

this is my function

```
    function download ($zipUrl, $zipFilename){

    $ch = curl_init();
    $fp = fopen ($zipFilename, 'w+');
    $ch = curl_init($zipUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "nvb=20160622094506&nva=20160622095506&hash=089366e5fe3da46f9caf2");

    curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);        



}
```

what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If curl_exec returns error, you can read that error with curl_error. Take a look what http code server returned so you can understand clearly what's going on.